# Pyright ... (triple dot) is not allowed in this context

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I am on python 3.11 and i am using type hints for annotations. I have a function parameter which takes list of any length, all elements should of type str, for this when I do the following:

```py
def create_input(columns: list[str, ...]):

    ...
```

Pyright throws an error in the editor saying triple dots are allowed in this context. But in the docs, it says it is okay. See image for reference. And [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#annotating-tuples)

[image]

Could some one please help, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `list[str]` is correct. The `…` is for `tuple[str, …]`, because `tuple` is heterogenous otherwise.

Comment: "I have a function parameter which takes list of any length, all elements should of type str, for this when I do the following:" - in your own words, why do you expect the code to have that effect? In particular, where the code says `: list[str, ...]`, what do you think this means, and *why* do you think it has that meaning?

Comment: "But in the docs, it says it is okay. See image for reference. And docs" - no, it does not. In fact, the very first example of a type annotation in the anchored section at your link, shows you exactly what to do instead; and it's not until the third code block that there's anything that looks like your code. My advice is to **read more carefully** the text between the code examples.

Comment: I apologise for any misunderstanding, I assumed lists are also hetergenous, as I have been using `[1, "1", None]` of such type without any issues. And I extended what the docs say about tuple to list as lists are more or less like tuple without immutability.